# TabHost - Text is wrapping

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost in my application and I have a problem that can be solved either way:

```
1) Reduce the font size of the text inside each tab.
2) Make the TabHost scroll-able so that the tabs aren't "scrunched".
```

Could you guys help me produce one of these two outputs?

I've already tried using a theme defining text size and referring to it through the android manifest inside the activity tag of the activity that holds the TabHost.

If needed I'll edit this post with my xml and class files.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeCIN.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend the second aproach. That's the one I've always used and it works like a charm. It consist in wrapping the TabWidget in a HorizontalScrollView with the scrollbar="none" attribute.

For instance (in your layout file):

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@+android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TabLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
      <TabWidget
        android:id="@+android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

You can find more info [here](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/)

Comment: This is actually quite brilliant! I really appreciate the quick response. I will most likely continue to use this approach in many future applications. *Bookmarks page*

Cheers man.